# Cannot wrap entity with interface because IDbSet interface is not covariant

Tags: c#, entity-framework, covariance

I'm using entity framework database first and I faced a problem that I cannot solve elegantly. Let's say in my autogenerated entity I have some proprties that I don't want to use (or I don't want to allow somebody to use them). So I came up with a good idea to write an interface which provide only a part of properties from the entity and I would like to use interface reference rather than exact entity class. For example let's say that I have an `Entity` table in database and this is the generated code and my interface (I don't want to even know about RedundantString column in database):

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    Type NavigationProperty { get; }
}

internal class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RedundantString { get; set; }
    public virtual Type NavigationProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is ok, however there is one problem. In my `DbContext` I have a property:

```
public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
```

As I said I do not want to have direct access to `Entity` type, I would rather use `IEntity`. So I want to pack my context in antother interface that would provide only property:

```
IDbSet<IEntity> Entities { get; }
```

Here is the problem. I can't implement that property using `IDbSet<Entity>` because IDbSet is not declared to be covariant, so common cast:

```
IDbSet<IEntity> IMyDbContext.Entities
{
    get { return (IDbSet<IEntity>)Entities; }
}
```

is compiling fine but throws a runtime exception.
What can I do to solve that problem?

Comment: Do you use your DbContext directly or there is some pattern on top of it, like repository?

Comment: Surely it would be simpler to remove the redundant properties from the entity class? EF doesn't care if there are columns in your table that don't map to properties on your entity. The only issue would be if the database requires a non-default value in the column for new records.